# Gutters "toggling" on Masonry (jQuery plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I am creating a homepage gallery using Masonry. It looks great, but there are several quirks that are giving me headaches.

I had originally tried to use percentage column widths, but after much frustration, I decided on just switching to a smaller container width for mobile and tablet users. The problem I am having now, is when the screen is shrunk, one of the divs loses its gutter. If the screen is resized again, the gutter returns. And if at any time, one of the divs registers a click, the layout is fixed. (In chrome that is. I haven't even begun looking at Firefox / IE, but it isn't pretty at the moment).

Here is the example:

http://headninja.com/sitetest/

Comment: Use the $(window).smartresize(function(){ see the metafizzy docs and, perhaps, their github project. Also, there's and error in your code:      <img class="model" src="img/asparfork.png" alt="Asparagus"< />

Comment: Thank you for the response, but is this an "Isotope" solution, or a "Masonry" solution? I am only using masonry for the time being, and can not find anything about smartresize in the Masonry docs.

Comment: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html

Comment: I am not using Isotope, I am using masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Then use the bindresize also when loaded at various sizes the layout breaks: http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#bindresize

Comment: Yes, I am just trying to get the masonry portion working for now. And unfortunately it looks like bindresize has not made a difference. Here are two screenshots of what I'm referring to: http://imgur.com/a/Ntebj

The two screenshots are taken on either side of the 1060 px "@media screen breaking point" for the css. You'll notice that the gutter between the first and second panels mysteriously disappears...

Comment: $container is not defined. In your implementation it's just container

Comment: Is it not defined on line 28? I'm relatively new to jQuery, is this incorrect somehow?

Comment: yes, there is no $ in your implementation of masonry -- either set it up as per the docs or refer to the variable without the $ preceeding. Besides needed that, you probably need ImagesLoaded. http://masonry.desandro.com/faq.html -- Get the Chrome developer tools and open up in console, you'll see the error. http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/jquery-basics